# Possible memory leak with WPF Custom Control?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, wpf, event-handling

I might have a potential memory leak with my custom control. Do I actually have one?

```
public interface IAlertable : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }

public sealed class AlertButton : Button
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasAlertPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasAlert", typeof(bool), typeof(AlertButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasAlertProperty = HasAlertPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlertContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AlertContext", typeof(IAlertable), typeof(AlertButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnAlertContextChanged, null, false, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));

    static AlertButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AlertButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AlertButton)));
    }

    private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedEventHandler { get; set; }

    public bool HasAlert
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasAlertProperty); }
        protected set { SetValue(HasAlertPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public IAlertable AlertContext
    {
        get { return (IAlertable )GetValue(AlertContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlertContextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnAlertContextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (AlertButton)d;

        obj.OnAlertContextChanged((IAlertable)e.OldValue, (IAlertable)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnAlertContextChanged(IAlertable prev, IAlertable curr)
    {
        if (prev != null)
        {
             UnhookEvents(prev);
        }
        if (curr != null)
        {
             HookEvents(curr);
        }
    }

    private void UnhookEvents(IAlertable context)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChangedEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            context.PropertyChanged -= handler;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler = null;
        }

        UpdateDependantProperties();
    }

    private void HookEvents(IAlertable context)
    {
        var handler = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);
        PropertyChangedEventHandler = handler;

        context.PropertyChanged += handler;

        UpdateDependantProperties();
    }
}
```

---

The part I'm worried about is that my custom control subscribes/unsubscribes from the `AlertContext`'s `PropertyChanged` event. But, what happens if I have the following scenario:

```
public sealed class MasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DetailViewModel> { get; private set; }

    // etc...
}

public sealed class DetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IAlertable AlertableObject { get; private set; }
    // etc...
}
```

Now, whenever I switch between detailed views, the user interface will create new `AlertButton`s each time, each of which will subscribe to the `AlertableObject`, but when I keep switching back and forth those objects are the same.

The reason I built things out the way I did in my custom control was because I saw that Microsoft did something similar with `ButtonBase.Command`:

```
    private static readonly UncommonField<EventHandler> CanExecuteChangedHandler = new UncommonField<EventHandler>();

    private void UnhookCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChangedHandler.GetValue(this); 
        if (handler != null)
        { 
            command.CanExecuteChanged -= handler; 
            CanExecuteChangedHandler.ClearValue(this);
        } 
        UpdateCanExecute();
    }

    private void HookCommand(ICommand command) 
    {
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(OnCanExecuteChanged); 
        CanExecuteChangedHandler.SetValue(this, handler); 
        command.CanExecuteChanged += handler;
        UpdateCanExecute(); 
    }
```

The only part that is strange (I don't fully understand it) is `UncommonField<T>`, but it still stands that the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event will still have a subscribed handler that is a property of the `ButtonBase` object. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: You are looking for the Weak Event Pattern, where subscribers to events only hold Weak References which allows the publisher of the event to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct, in some cases `ICommand` can leak memory too! Usually it does not happen, because most implementations of `ICommand` either utilize `CommandManager` (which uses weak references) or do not care about `CanExecute` state and therefore use empty `CanExecuteChanged` event, which does not hold any references at all. But if you implement `CanExecuteChanged` as strong event, `ICommand` will cause memory leak.

In your case the simplest solution would probably be to additionally `UnhookEvents` when control is unloaded, and to `HookEvents` when it is loaded.

Alternatively, you can use [weak events pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970850%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as Zache suggested.